# Find log statements which loose exception stacktrace

Tags: java, log4j

I came across code written by somebody which caught some exception and tried logging that as ERROR without printing stacktrace.
I expected below usage

```
log.error("message", exception);
```

However it was

```
log.error("message");
```

How to catch such coding errors by static code analyzers or any such tool?

Comment: Maybe FindBugs has a rule for that (or lets you define one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) and do a **File Search** over your Workspace with **Regular Expression** like this:

```
^.*\.(error|debug|info)\([^,]*\);$
```

This is the best option as you will see the results in the Search panel and be able to jump to the files/lines directly with double-click.

Also a simple editor like [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) can do the job with its **Find in Files** option with **Regular expressions** enabled. Unfortunately, the Notepad++ is not able to do a regex `OR` like `(this|that)` so to find `log.debug(...)`s and `log.info(...)`s you would need to replace the `error` keyword manually. Just select the directory of your project and use a pattern like this:

```
^.*\.error\([^,]*\);$
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find all usages for Log.error(String) in your IDE and check they are not in a catch Exception block.  This is not the sort of thing you should be having to check regularly, i.e. it is better to learn from your mistakes.